# select regular expression in Python

Tags: python

I have a string, which is

```
"contributors_enabled": false, "geo_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Nov 11 15:38:06 +0000 2016"}, "text": "Facts On Managed Forex Trading htps:////t.co////E4cxCvvjD #forex #binaryoptions #cryptocurrency #stockmarket", "timestamp_ms": "1509073455803",.
```

I am going to use regular expression select the text:

```
Facts On Managed Forex Trading htps:////t.co////E4cxCvvjD #forex #binaryoptions #cryptocurrency #stockmarket
```

which is after  "text": " and before ", "timestamp_ms":

Is it possible to collect these text?

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser instead? That will be far less error-prone and much more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though from string it seems your entire string could potentially be parsed as it seems it is JSON. However, since you're looking for regex related solution I hope following works for you.

```
import re

pattern = '"text": "(.*), "timestamp_ms"'

str = """
"contributors_enabled": false, "geo_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Nov 11 15:38:06 +0000 2016"}, "text": "Facts On Managed Forex Trading htps:////t.co////E4cxCvvjD #forex #binaryoptions #cryptocurrency #stockmarket", "timestamp_ms": "1509073455803",.
"""

print re.findall(pattern, string=str)[0]
```

**output:**

```
Facts On Managed Forex Trading htps:////t.co////E4cxCvvjD #forex #binaryoptions #cryptocurrency #stockmarket"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible?** Yes.

```
def text_scrap(text, start, end):
    """This function returns the data between start and end."""
    _,_,rest = text.partition(start)
    result,_,_ = rest.partition(end)
    return result

my_text = "contributors_enabled": false, "geo_enabled": false, "created_at": "Fri Nov 11 15:38:06 +0000 2016"}, "text": "Facts On Managed Forex Trading htps:////t.co////E4cxCvvjD #forex #binaryoptions #cryptocurrency #stockmarket", "timestamp_ms": "1509073455803",.

data_scrapped = text_scrap(my_text, start=' "text": "', end="timestamp_ms") # use our new shiny function
print(data_scrapped)
```

**Good idea?** Probably not.

Your code is a dict, so you can more easily access to the "text" key of the dict. Please check [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) to learn about dicts.